# Finding coordinates of Koch Curve

Tags: algorithm, math, linear-algebra, graph-algorithm, graphic

Sorry for my language since English is my second language.

I am trying to convert a straight line into a fractal known as Koch curve.
The 2 points of the straight line are given and then I need to create the Koch curve where I divide the line to 3 segments and then make the second segment an equilateral triangle.
See http://www.tgmdev.be/curvevonkoch.php.

So far we convert the straight line to 4 equally segments, and I need to figure out all the coordinates of the Koch curve.

I have thought of a straight line when the y coordinates of the 2 point are the same which give me horizontal line. if so, I can figure out the 3 points of equilateral triangle by dividing the second segment half and taking the cos(60) of the right triangle.
as here:
http://www.themathpage.com/atrig/30-60-90-triangle.htm

My problem is how to find all coordinates when the stright line is diagonal, for example a(200,100), b(400,600) or a(400,500), b(100,500).

Answer (score 8):

If your base segment is AB, with A(Ax,Ay) and B(Bx,By), then the 4 sub-segments will be
AP, PQ, QR, RB as defined below.

First define two orthogonal vectors of same length:

```
U(Bx-Ax,By-Ay) and
V(Ay-By,Bx-Ax)
```

Then the points:

```
P=A+(1/3)*U
Q=A+(1/2)*U+(sqrt(3)/6)*V
R=A+(2/3)*U
```

The point+vector=point notation is similar to a translation.

Example with A(100,100) and B(400,100):

```
U(300,0)
V(0,300)
P = (100,100) + (1/3)*(300,0) = (200,100)
Q = (100,100) + (1/2)*(300,0) + (sqrt(3)/6)*(0,300) = (250,186)
R = (100,100) + (2/3)*(300,0) = (300,100)
```

Comment: I could not get the point by the formula you provided:
I consider that A(100,100),B(400,100) and then U(300,0),V(0,300) 
but I could not go further with the point, can you explain how to get the point by using your equations

Comment: Added an example with your data.

Comment: Yes that was very helpful, I also try another example for diagonal line where a(400,100), b(100,400) and then 
U(-300,300)
V(-300,-300)

P(300,200)
Q(164,164)
R(200,300)

Am I getting them correct??

Comment: Hi Mr.Bainville, I have considered your formula in my research, can you give me a reference of the formula plz? Since I have to get a reference in order to officially use it.

Comment: Hi Mr.Bainville, I have considered your formula in my research, can you give me a reference of the formula plz? Since I have to get a reference in order to officially use it.

Comment: I think the "Trigonometry" page on Wikipedia provides enough material to reconstruct the formulas.  Maybe a little bit of "Affine space" and "Vector space" would be useful too.

Comment: Thank you very much Eric.It's has been really a great help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript function based on Eric's algorithm.

```
export function getChildLinePoints (points, depth = 0) {
  if (depth === 0) {
    const Ax = points[0]
    const Ay = points[1]
    const Bx = points[2]
    const By = points[3]
    const Ux = Bx - Ax
    const Uy = By - Ay
    const Vx = Ay - By
    const Vy = Bx - Ax
    const Px = Ax + ((1 / 3) * Ux)
    const Py = Ay + ((1 / 3) * Uy)
    const Qx = Ax + ((1 / 2) * Ux) + ((Math.sqrt(3) / 6) * Vx)
    const Qy = Ay + ((1 / 2) * Uy) + ((Math.sqrt(3) / 6) * Vy)
    const Rx = Ax + ((2 / 3) * Ux)
    const Ry = Ay + ((2 / 3) * Uy)
    return [[
      Ax, Ay,
      Px, Py
    ], [
      Px, Py,
      Qx, Qy
    ], [
      Qx, Qy,
      Rx, Ry
    ], [
      Rx, Ry,
      Bx, By
    ]]
  } else {
    const xpoints = [...getChildLinePoints(points, depth - 1)]
    return xpoints.reduce((acc, point) => [...acc, ...getChildLinePoints(point)], [])
  }
}
```