# How to simplify this Blockly program drawing a snowflake?

Tags: blockly

The question says that:

> The program shown below on the left draws a snowflake. It uses 33 code blocks.
> Can you re-write it so that it uses at least one function and less than 30 blocks.

[image] [image]

How can I draw this using Blockly?

Comment: please show your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I don't think recursive function is the solution in this case but in python I would try something like this

```
def drawLeaf(direction):
    // Draw your leaf in this direction using your blocks code

for direction in [0, 72, 144, 216, 288]:
    drawLeaf(direction)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, please have a look at [Finding coordinates of Koch Curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367165/finding-coordinates-of-koch-curve)

And here's a Java code snippet (for Android) to draw koch snowflake.It's a simple recursive function

```java
public void drawfractal1(Canvas canvas , float x1 , float y1 , float x2 , float y2, int level){
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        int r = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 256);
        int g = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 256);
        int b = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 256);
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(r,g,b));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(7);

        if(level==0) {
            canvas.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,paint);
        }
        else{
            float ux = x2-x1;
            float uy = y2-y1;
            float vx = y1-y2;
            float vy = x2-x1;

            float xa = x1 + ux/3;
            float ya = y1 + uy/3;
            float xb = x1 + ux/2 + (float) sqrt(3)*vx/6;
            float yb = y1 +uy/2 + (float)sqrt(3)*vy/6;
            float xc = x1 + 2*ux/3;
            float yc = y1 + 2*uy/3;
            drawfractal1(canvas , x1,y1,xa,ya,level-1);
            drawfractal1(canvas , xa,ya,xb,yb,level-1);
            drawfractal1(canvas , xb,yb,xc,yc,level-1);
            drawfractal1(canvas , xc,yc,x2,y2,level-1);
        }
    }
```